# How to do alignment in jQuery (text is not able to display at front of time)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am doing work with web service actually I am facing a problem that my web service text is not showing up in front of time. I need to show the text in front of time.

I do like that.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="timeID" class ="left">
        </div>
        <div id="realTimeContents" class = "right realtimeContend_h">
        </div>
        <div class="cursor" style="font-size:23px;">|</div>
    </div>
</div>

function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
{
     var currentTime = new Date()
     var hours = currentTime.getHours()
     var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

     if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes

     $('#timeID').append("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>");
     $('#realTimeContents').prepend('<p>'+result+'</p>');
}
```

My output look like this..

But I need like that .

```
6:30 Demo file not found
6:30 .
6:30  it
6:30 ic
6:31 ic
6:31 hi UI
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you want your output to look like:

`6:30 Demo file not fount`

But you have two separate divs that you are populating. One you are populating with just the time. The other you are populating with result.

If you need the two together why arn't you appending just that?

`$('#timeID').append("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b> " + result + "<br/>");`

Why have the two separate divs if you want the time and the result on the same line?

Maybe I misunderstood your question.

**UPDATE**: Since result contains newlines and you want the time next to every new line try this:

`var lines = result.split('<br/>');`

```
$.each(lines, function(){
  var text = "<span style='margin-left: 10px;'>" + this + "</span>";
  $('#timeID').append("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b> " + text + "<br/>");
});
```

Please note that this splits on specifically `<br/>` if the returned result has line breaks that look differently like `<br>` you will need to change the split.

Comment: actually you understand my problem ..!! actually I am trying  to solve but after taking  two div i am not able to solve..!! now i am checking your answer..!!

Comment: Yes i am getting the result little bit..!!

Comment: I am getting the resukt like that ..check my update ..!!is this possible to show time when there is a new line..?

Comment: awesome answer thanks man...!!!!one more question is it possible to autoscroll the result..?

Comment: can it's possible that result is autoscroll mean if data coming large (as it is coming) it start scrolling (as in chat example)?secondly can we give some left padding in result because it's is to near to date..?

Comment: any one get any solution..?

Comment: Try `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` to scroll the page to the bottom. I updated my answer to add margin to the result.

Comment: Is this possible to show loading image while i am getting data from server actually i did the same in native application that till upto we show loading image untill we get server data is this possible in jquert

Comment: You can try somthing like this. Add the loading image into your html. `<img id="loadingImg" src="xxx" />`. In your javascript before you call for the result hide the timeID div `$('#timeID').hide()`. Then after you're done calling your resultHandler you can hide the loading image `$('#loadingImg').hide()` and unhide the timeID div which will now have all the data in it `$('#timeID').show()`