# Auto scrolling content of div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to do vertical auto scroll? Actually I am working on socket programming and I am getting data after a regular interval of time.

I need if the data goes more than page it start vertical scrolling (not manually). User is able to do do manually, but if she does not want to do that it should start scrolling vertically .

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="timeID" class="left"></div>
    </div>        

function nativePluginResultHandler(result) {
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    var lines = result.split('<br/>');
    $.each(lines, function () {
        $('#timeID').append("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b> " + this + "<br/>");
    });
}
```

I need to automatically scroll the div `timeID`.

Comment: like that ..<div id="timeID" class="left overflow:scroll "></div>?

Comment: I think i need to use setinterval do some scrolling task after a regular interval of time

Comment: Refer to this example [overflow-sytle](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow-y&preval=scroll)

Comment: ok checking..tell you in 5 min...

Comment: Not working..:( need to think other way..

Comment: I think you can't understand my problem.Problem is that data is coming regular interval of time like in chat in Facebook.i want it scroll automatically if lage data

Comment: see the image here in this ,..I am getting data like that ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893302/how-to-do-alingment-in-jquey-text-is-not-able-to-display-at-front-of-time

Comment: ok...i will try but you can't get server response..:(

Comment: take this example on fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/cN7SD/.some data is display but it is not scrolling..?

Comment: Buddy you forgot to specify div height and width.Please specify its height.

Comment: ok please change in my fiddle?

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/cN7SD/1/

Comment: Thanks sir ..!! I am checking ..i will tell you after 5 min ..I have one more question show /hide loader because while getting data from server i need to show loader image..?

Comment: Working.....loader image..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple example

```
<div id="scroll_y" style="width:100%;height:500px;">
<!--put your all stuff Here-->
<div>

#scroll_y {
   overflow-y:scroll;
}

setInterval(function () {
   $('#timeID').append('it works' + new Date());
    var elem = document.getElementById('timeID');// just to scroll down the line 
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
},30);
```